# when i download html code in pdf format get file extention crdownload

Tags: html, reactjs, download

when i download jsx code in react js when download in crdownload format
how to solve this

`const generatePDF = (data) => { const invoice = document.getElementById("invoice"); const fileName =`${data?.name}-${isCounterNumber?.paymentNumber}.pdf`;
var opt = {
margin: 0,
filename: fileName,
image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
html2canvas: {
scale: 2
},
jsPDF: {
unit: 'in',
format: 'a4',
orientation: 'portrait'
}
};

```
    const pdfExporter = html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt);

    pdfExporter.toPdf().get('pdf').then(function (pdf) {
        pdf.save(fileName);
        //pdf Create a Blob from the PDF data
        const blob = new Blob([pdf.output('blob')], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        // Create a URL for the Blob
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        // Open the PDF in a new tab
        const newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');
        // Print the PDF after it's loaded
        newTab.onload = function () {
            newTab.print();
        };
    });
}`
```